# Question regarding infopath ad Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to buy Sharpoint for 1 person/user..? I need it but have been informed that it is not possible.

If it is not possible, can anyone explain..?
If it is possible, can anyone inform me why I can buy it..?

Comment: Are you talking about SharePoint online?  If not, you can download SharePoint Foundation for free.  You will also need SQL in order to run it.  In theory you can provision the permissions to apply to only one person.  If there are more people that need it, you can restrict permissions for a site. library, list to one person while still utilizing the collaborative nature of SharePoint for other users in other sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use InfoPath and SharePoint for a single user than look at an SharePoint Online subscription.

For installing locally, it's not worth it when we are talking about the standard or enterprise SKU's.  The costs for licensing alone would make it a horrible value investment for a single user.  Technically you have to license more than a single user -I believe the smallest unit you can start with is 5 users, but this will be the lowest part of the total cost to be honest (server licensing, hardware resources, etc).

Other alternatives are getting an MSDN Subscriptions if you only want to deploy and test things internal (but not use in production). Besides MSDN - your organization may be able to sign up for Microsoft Partnership Program, which may grant you access to software with Internal User Rights, that you can use in production (please make sure you qualify to participate - Microsoft doesn't look kindly at organizations that try to game their licensing).  If you can't or don't qualify for that - there are other programs like DreamSpark where Microsoft grants you access to their server software.